# Probability Task | Need help figuring out what to do next.

Tags: probability

Here is a task that I am trying to un-cracK.

We have the deck of 60 playing cards in which there are 25 different red cards, 20 different
green cards and 15 different white cards. We draw 7 cards. **What is the probability of
having at least 3 red and 2 green cards in our draw**

So far, I have calculated the possible ways, we can draw 7 cards

( 60| 7 )  = 386206920

And listed all the favourable scenarios, there is a total of 6 of them

R = 3  G = 2  W = 2
R = 3  G = 3  W = 1
R = 3  G = 4  W = 0
R = 3  G = 2  W = 1
R = 3  G = 3  W = 0
R = 3  G = 2  W = 0

Could anyone please guide in the right possible direction on what should be done next, I am kind of stuck right now as this task appears to be a bit hard.

Will appreciate all the help I can get, thanks.

Comment: Consider $\displaystyle ~\binom{25}{r} \times \binom{20}{g} \times \binom{15}{w}.$